# What is the difference between institution and department?

Tags: meaning

When I submitted manuscript to journal, I was asked to finish information on institution and/or department from, I'm a teacher of a college in an university, so, I filled the college in the institution column and university in the department column. it's right or not?

Comment: See also [academia.se]

Answer (score 2):

Er ... no.

Unless the College has departments, you should put the University as the Institution, and the College as the department.

An exception might be if you were submitting a paper sponsored by a particular research institute in your Uni, then you would discuss with them how to represent yourself.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding would be to put the University and College as the Institution, and the Department would refer to the area of study, like "Board of Mathematics."

Answer (score 2):

Many universities have several colleges and schools, and each college or school had its departments. It would be rather incomplete to not mention the name of a department, such as

- Bioengineering
- Chemical and Biomolecular Engineering
- Civil and Environmental Engineering
- Computer Science
- etc.

Another school or college at the same university (on the same campus) may have departments  with some of the same or similar names, e.g., Computer Science.

So you make a more complete statement of your pedigree by stating something like

> **John Hopkins University School of Medicine, Department of Neuroscience**

or

> **University of California at Los Angeles, School of Engineering and Applied Science, Department of Computer Science**

with all of the pomp that deservedly goes with it.